how to strengthen cellophane while keeping it clear and foldable
We are trying to strengthen the clear marerial made of cellophane - types 165 (uncoated and thinner) and 180 (coated to increase impermeability and thicker). We want to keep it flexible and foldable, while preventing ripping. We also want it transparent.
These are our initial findings in the PDF but we would like additional comments and feedback to help guide us.
Google Drive Link to the PDF file:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-fx3GxV3B1IRi22c1_SWddWoKFlzg9mg/view?usp=sharing
Our various experiments (all failed) in combining different substances to cellophane to produce a more durable material that still keeps clear and transparent (or not becoming sticky). A chemical engineer recommended applying clear Elmer's glue or clear wood glue on the surface of cellophane, so we might try that in the meantime.
We are not experts, so we need your help.
Thank you!
P. S. Is there any other archival material(s) (we recently found out that cellophane is not archival) that is pliable/foldable, resistant to tearing, and transparent? (Archival as in fine art archival quality that lasts materially.)

Just a generality: the purer the material, in many cases, the longer it lasts. For example, paper with more lignin (e.g., newsprint, https://science.howstuffworks.com/question463.htm) yellows faster than that made with purer cellulose. Rather than trying to add to a medium, take away what makes it age.

We did not synthesize the material. Therefore we do have control over goes in and cannot subtract materials. I am still looking for an answer to the question above
